# SQL Procedures - Comparing values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to create a procedure that adds information into a table after some checks are done. One of the checks requires comparing if a field from another table already exists within the other table. I am currently trying to find a way to compare a single field to an entire column of another table to see if any of them match.
Eg. The single field is `PrerequisiteID` and I need to make sure that this ID exists in the **Course** table under `CourseID`. I am struggling to work out how to compare the single `prerequisiteID` to the whole column of `courseID`. Any help would be appreciated.

The actual question I am doing is:

> Write a procedure **NEW_COURSE** that uses the given course details in order to offer a brand new course. Before opening a new course, the procedure ensures that:
>
> 1. The prerequisite courses for it (if any) already exist in the **COURSE** table. For simplicity, we will pretend that a course can have at most one course as prerequisite.
> 2. The prerequisite for a course must be at a lower level. For instance, the prerequisite for ISYS326 must be a100- or 200-level course, and cannot be a 300 level course.
>
> If either of the above requirements fails, the procedure raises an exception `WRONG_PREREQ` that prints an appropriate alert message, and does not modify the **COURSE** table.

Table Structure:

```
create table COURSE ( 
    COURSEID CHAR(8) not null, 
    DEPTID CHAR(8) not null, 
    COURSENAME VARCHAR2(20), 
    TEXTBOOK VARCHAR2(20), 
    CREDITHOUR NUMBER(2), 
    MAX_ENROL NUMBER(4), 
    ACTUAL_ENROL NUMBER(4), 
    AVAILABILITY NUMBER(4), 
    constraint PK_COURSE primary key (COURSEID) 
);

create table HAS_PREREQUISITE ( 
    COURSEID CHAR(8) not null, 
    PREREQUISITEID CHAR(8) not null, 
    constraint PK_HAS_PREREQUISITE primary key (COURSEID, PREREQUISITEID) 
); 

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE 
add constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
references COURSE (COURSEID); 

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE 
add constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE1 foreign key (PREREQUISITEID) 
references COURSE (COURSEID);
```

This is my procedure so far, I know it is incorrect I am just trying to get something on there:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE NEW_COURSE
(
    c_course_ID      COURSE.COURSEID%type,
    c_dept_ID         COURSE.DEPTID%type,
    c_coursename    COURSE.COURSENAME%type,
    c_textbook         COURSE.TEXTBOOK%type,
    c_credithour       COURSE.CREDITHOUR%type,
    c_max_enrol       COURSE.MAX_ENROL%type,
    c_actual_enrol    COURSE.ACTUAL_ENROL%type,
    c_availability      COURSE.AVAILABILITY%type,
    p_prerequisite_ID  HAS_PREREQUISITE.PREREQUISITEID%type
)

IS

BEGIN
  
  IF (p_prerequisite_ID != COURSE.courseID) THEN WRONG_PREREQ (-20205, 'That prerequisite does not exist');
  ELSE IF( p_prerequisite_ID > c_course_ID) THEN WRONG_PREREQ(-20205, 'That is not a valid prerequisite');
  ELSE
  INSERT INTO COURSE (COURSEID, DEPTID, COURSENAME, TEXTBOOK, CREDITHOUR, MAX_ENROL, ACTUAL_ENROL, AVAILABILITY)
  VALUES (c_course_ID, c_dept_ID, c_coursename, c_textbook, c_credithour, c_max_enrol, c_actual_enrol, c_availability);
  END IF; 

END NEW_COURSE;
```

Data for COURSE:

```
+----------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| CourseID |  DeptID  | COURSENAME | TEXTBOOK | CREDITHOUR | MAX_ENROL | ACTUAL_ENROL | AVAILABILITY |
+----------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| ISYS224  | FSE      |            |          |            |           |              |              |
| COMP225  | FSE      |            |          |            |           |              |              |
| ISYS114  | FSE      |            |          |            |           |              |              |
| COMP115  | FSE      |            |          |            |           |              |              |
+----------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

Prerequisite does not have any data but here is the table definition for it:

```
+----------------+--------------+
|  Column Name   |  Data Type   |
+----------------+--------------+
| COURSEID       | CHAR(8 BYTE) |
| PREREQUISITEID | CHAR(8 BYTE) |
+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Show the layout of your tables

Comment: create table COURSE 
(
   COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,
   DEPTID               CHAR(8)              not null,
   COURSENAME           VARCHAR2(20),
   TEXTBOOK             VARCHAR2(20),
   CREDITHOUR           NUMBER(2),
   MAX_ENROL            NUMBER(4),
   ACTUAL_ENROL         NUMBER(4),
   AVAILABILITY         NUMBER(4),
   constraint PK_COURSE primary key (COURSEID)
);

Comment: create table HAS_PREREQUISITE 
(
   COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,
   PREREQUISITEID       CHAR(8)              not null,
   constraint PK_HAS_PREREQUISITE primary key (COURSEID, PREREQUISITEID)
);

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   add constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   add constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE1 foreign key (PREREQUISITEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

Comment: that's how the 2 tables were created and the constraints on them, im not sure how to post an image or anything here, otherwise I would add that in

Comment: Use this website https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/

Comment: In your case, wont the FK already make the check for you?

Comment: that was my thought however the question i'm working on ask for this: "The prerequisite courses for it (if any) already exist in the COURSE table. For simplicity, we will pretend that a course can have at most one course as prerequisite." So i assume that I have to make the check manually (?)

Comment: Is this some sort of assignment qn? If yes, post the full qn pls; it seems that your quotes does not contain the qn. If no, the FK does exactly the checking for you.

Comment: yeah it is, this is the full question
"Write a procedure NEW_COURSE that uses the given course details in order to offer a brand new
course. Before opening a new course, the procedure ensures that:
1. The prerequisite courses for it (if any) already exist in the COURSE table. For simplicity,
we will pretend that a course can have at most one course as prerequisite.

Comment: 2. The prerequisite for a course must be at a lower level. For instance, the prerequisite for
ISYS326 must be a100- or 200-level course, and cannot be a 300 level course. 
If either of the above requirements fails, the procedure raises an exception WRONG_PREREQ
that prints an appropriate alert message, and does not modify the COURSE table. "

this is the second half of the question

Comment: The question is quite obvious that you are trying to do a TRY CATCH to (raise an exception) and do not do anything or ROLLBACK (does not modify) when the error is present

Comment: okay, I kind of pseudo coded out what i thought would be correct: "
DECLARE
all the variables for the table

BEGIN

IF prerequisiteID != any courseID in COURSE then raise flag

ELSE IF prerequisiteID > courseID then raise flag

ELSE insert information"

however i'm stuck on how to check these conditions, i'm also pretty new to sql procedures which isn't helping, but I think my logic is correct

Comment: @Ben, please try to [edit] your question instead of posting in comment, thanks.

Comment: sorry about that @Alex, updated the question!

Comment: Thanks, but if it is possible, please add sample data (as your requirement 2 is related to the data), and tag the database for this question

Comment: No worries for the data, how do I tag the database, I've never actually posted a question before so it's all pretty new.

Comment: The first link you added is the data, but please use the link C2H50H provided, turn that into text and paste it in your question.  Which database you are using, not tag `database`, it should be something like `SQL Server`, `Oracle`, `MySQL`... etc

Comment: should be sorted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what we have here is a smart key, and smart keys are dumb (because they are difficult to validate and always entail extra code on the part of the consuming program). The COURSEID `ISYS224` breaks down into three components:

- `ISYS` = subject
- `2` = course level
- `24` = class number (say)

If your data model were correct (and clearly it's your teacher's fault that it is not) the solution would have been simple because the query would be obvious.

As it is, you need to break down the COURSEID into its constituent parts yourself. Let's assume that SUBJECT is always four characters long, because anything else would be sadistic. Then the query is:

```
select c.courseid
from course c 
where substr(c.courseid, 1, 4) = substr(p_prerequisite_id, 1, 4)
and substr(c.courseid, 5, 1) < substr(p_prerequisite_id, 5, 1)
;
```

This will hurl NO_DATA_FOUND if the prerequisite does not fit the rules. Use an exception section to handle this neatly.

Alternatively you could select the prerequisite course record into a local variable and do the chopping in PL/SQL code.

```
select c.courseid into l_prerequisite_course
from course c 
where c.courseid = p_prerequisite_id;

if substr(l_prerequisite_course, 1, 4) = substr(p_prerequisite_id, 1, 4)
or substr(l_prerequisite_course, 5, 1) < substr(p_prerequisite_id, 5, 1)
then raise ...
;
```

Comment: Thank you heaps, that actually makes a lot more sense once it's broken down